# Как сохранить и вывести кавычки?

Tags: html, php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Пишу сайт с вводом данных в базу данных mysql через форму html с помощью php.
Возникла проблема с сохранением и последующим выводом строк содержащих кавычки (' и ").
Строки не сохраняются в базу данных, при экранировании кавычек (функцией addslashes()) сохраняются, но не выводятся.
Вот код поля ввода начальной страницы:

```
echo '< input type="text" size="20" name="tender1" value="" />';
```

Код код поля после правки:

```
echo '< input type="text" size="20" name="tender1" value="'.$_REQUEST['tender1'].'" />';
```

Коды сохранения в базу данных (добавление и изменение):

```
mysql_query('INSERT INTO tenders (`tender1`) VALUES ("'.$_REQUEST['tender1'].'")');  
mysql_query('UPDATE `tenders` SET `tender1`="'.$_REQUEST['tender1'].'"');
```

Код вывода из базы данных:

```
$mysql_array_tenders = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `tenders`),0); 
echo '< input type="text" size="20" name="tender1" value="'.$mysql_array_tenders['tender1'].'" />';
```

Подскажите как изменить код что бы при сохранении и выводе строк содержащих кавычки (' и ") не возникало проблем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Входящие данные обрабатывать с помощью mysql_real_escape_string

```
mysql_query('INSERT INTO tenders (`tender1`) VALUES ("'.mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['tender1']).'")');
```